# Edimax 8192cu wifi dongle can't connect to hidden network

Tags: networking, wifi

I've tried many ways to connect to a Hidden WiFi network from a raspberry pi but none of them seem to work. My raspberry pi is able to detect that there is a network but it cannot map it to it. I ran the following command:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo iwlist wlan1 scan essid "MYSSID"
wlan1     Scan completed :
      Cell 01 - Address: //redacted//
                ESSID:"Not my wifi"
                Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
                Mode:Master
                Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                Encryption key:on
                Bit Rates:65 Mb/s
                Extra:wpa_ie=//redacted//
                IE: WPA Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                Quality=58/100  Signal level=100/100
      Cell 02 - Address: //redacted//
                ESSID:"Some other wifi"
                Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
                Mode:Master
                Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                Encryption key:on
                Bit Rates:65 Mb/s
                Extra:wpa_ie=//redacted//
                IE: WPA Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                Quality=54/100  Signal level=23/100
      Cell 03 - Address: //redacted//
                ESSID:""
                Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
                Mode:Master
                Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                Encryption key:on
                Bit Rates:130 Mb/s
                Extra:rsn_ie=//redacted//
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : CCMP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                Quality=100/100  Signal level=42/100
```

Any insight of how I could connect to it would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

my /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 10.10.10.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan1
allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

iface wlan1 inet dhcp
up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat
```

my /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1


network={
        ssid="MYSSID"
        scan_ssid=1
        mode=0
        proto=WPA2
        pairwise=TKIP
        group=TKIP
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        psk="password"
}
```

I tried both ways to connect to the network, I added the contents of the file.

Another thing I noticed while testing with other Hidden networks is that, if I run the essid scan on them, if the hidden network is picked up only then is the Pi able to establish a connection.

Comment: Include the contents of `/etc/network/interfaces` and `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`

Answer (score 1):

Your `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` looks OK and includes the `scan_ssid=1` which should have it scan hidden networks, but you **never call it**.

Include the following in your `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

This is pretty much the normal setting of this file.

I do not know the detail of the parameters you have in your `/etc/network/interfaces`, but they do not seem the same as those in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`

It is better practice to include security detail in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` as only root can view it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize I pasted the wrong file, I was trying something. I pasted the version that I was trying before hand with wpa_supplicant.conf

Answer (score 0):

Did you get it working?

[These instructions](http://www.dafinga.net/2013/01/how-to-setup-raspberry-pi-with-hidden.html) did it for me.